# simple relative path question

Tags: java, path

In a relative path, what's the difference between **~/directory/subdirectory**  and  **./directory/subdirectory**?

Comment: what platform and/or language are you referring too?

Comment: Does `~/` work in Windows? Are you using Cygwin? (not mentioning the `/`...)

Comment: @ring0 IIRC, I think some (most?) path-related Java libraries allow you to use forward slashes for paths on both Linux/Windows - the libraries convert them for you using `File.seperator`. IIRC, that is.

Comment: ~ doesnot work in Windows, it must be Unix/Linux or some Unix/Linux simulator environment. And how is this related to Java. You should change the tags to Unix rather than java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux, `~` is your home directory, while `.` is the current directory, so those pathes are the same when you are in your home directory (since `.` is `~`), but not in other cases.

`~/directory/subdirectory` refers to `subdirectory` folder inside `directory` folder, inside your home folder.

`./directory/subdirectory` refers to `subdirectory` folder inside `directory` folder, inside current execution folder.

Answer (score 0):

~/directory/subdirectory for any particular user, is an absolute path instead. It referes to "directory/subdirectory" inside the user's home directory.

./directory/subdirectory is a relative path. It referes to "directory/subdirectory" inside the current directory (output of pwd command).